# What is a Span in syn?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a function arg and other things in `syn` and often I see a need for a span:

```rust
FnArg::Typed(PatType {
    attrs: vec![],
    pat: Box::new(Pat::Ident(PatIdent {
        attrs: vec![],
        by_ref: Some(Ref { span: ? }),
        mutability: None,
        ident: Ident::new(struct_name.as_str(), ?),
        subpat: None,
    })),
    colon_token: Colon { spans: item_impl. },
    ty: todo!(),
})
```

which is not even from `syn` but from `proc_macro`.

What exactly is a `Span` and what do I need to put in `span` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Span` is the information about where a token is textually located in a file (i.e. the line and column numbers), as well what macro (if any) generated it.

The compiler uses the span information of a token in two major ways:

- Error reporting. If a parser or compiler error occurs relating to the token, it will report the error using the token's span.

  Properly maintaining the span of tokens you generate can be the difference between a compiler error highlighting only the relevant part inside of a procedural macro versus highlighting the entire procedural macro body.
- Macro hygiene. Rust macros' hygiene system means that variables, labels, etc declared inside of a `macro_rules` macro are not visible to the call site, and vice versa, without explicitly passing them in, even if they use the same name. The span contains the info about what "context" a variable was declared in, so that they don't conflict.

What span to use is context dependent and based a lot on what you are using your procedural macro for. My general advice is, if you are generating some code "based on" some input to the procedural macro, try to copy the span of the tokens that most influence that generated code, so that if there is an error, the cause of it will be easily identifiable.